# Display image src mapped with Url.Content using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using a jquery imagezoom plugin, but the image is not displaying on zoom, I realized the javascript code cannot pick the image source because am using Url.Content to map my image and folder. Please any help on how i can work around this. Below is my code snippet

```
 ViewBag.ImagePath = "~/UploadedFiles/";
 string sep = "/";
 <img src="@Url.Content(ViewBag.ImagePath + Model.ProductName + sep + Model.SubImage)"  data-imagezoom=" true" class="img-responsive">
 Var sce = $("#mainimage img").prop('src')
```

I have also tried setting it with javascript like this but to no avail.

```
var urlmain = '@Url.Content(ViewBag.ImagePath + Model.ProductName + sep + Model.MainImage)';
var urlsub = '@Url.Content(ViewBag.ImagePath + Model.ProductName + sep + Model.SubImage)';
var urlsubii = '@Url.Content(ViewBag.ImagePath + Model.ProductName + sep + Model.SubImageII)';
$("#mainimage").prop('src', urlmain);  
$("#subimage").prop('src', urlsub);
$("#subimageii").prop('src', urlsubii);
```

This is what the html generated looks like

```
<img src="/UploadedFiles/On the other/pc4.jpg" data-imagezoom=" true" class="img-responsive" draggable="false">
```

Thanks in anticipation for your response.

Comment: what are the values in `Model.ProductName` and `Model.SubImage` ?

Comment: add generated html in question.

Comment: Capture URLs in data attribute and use data attribute in your JavaScript.

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad  this is what the generated source looks like <img src="/UploadedFiles/On the other/pc4.jpg" data-imagezoom=" true" class="img-responsive" draggable="false">